# Reihenfolge von Satzgliedern im Satz

Tags: sentence-structure, grammaticality

Auf welcher Position stehen die Satzglieder korrekt im Satz? Und warum?

1) Ich kaufe dir eine schöne Blume zum Geburtstag im Geschäft.

2) Ich kaufe dir morgen eine schöne Blume zum Geburtstag im Geschäft.

3) Ich kaufe nicht dir morgen eine schöne Blume zum Geburtstag im Geschäft?

Comment: Die Beispielsätze sind etwas unrealistisch, denn "im Geschäft" würde man in der Praxis einfach nicht sagen (auch wenn man theoretisch könnte). "Kaufen" impliziert "im Geschäft", das muss man nicht dazusagen.

Comment: Ich kaufe Blumen gerne am Wochenmarkt, also im Freien. Daher kann es durchaus sinnvoll sein, das Geschäft ausdrücklich zu erwähnen.

Comment: @ChristianGeiselmann Die Probleme, die der Einzelhandel mit Online-Shops hat, deuten darauf hin, dass ein Kauf schon länger nicht mehr den Gang ins Geschäft impliziert.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1 und 2 sind korrekt und praktisch gleich Du hast lediglich in 2) das Wort "morgen" (an der richtigen Stelle) hinzugefügt. 
Auch wenn ich es etwas anders formulieren würde z.B.:

> Ich kaufe dir (morgen) zum Geburtstag eine schöne Blume im Geschäft

das klingt für mich etwas flüssiger. "(morgen)" für variante 2.

3) ist falsch: Es müsste -in deinem Satz- heißen:

> Ich kaufe dir morgen nicht eine schöne Blume zum Geburtstag im Geschäft.
>
> Ich kaufe dir nicht morgen eine schöne Blume zum Geburtstag im Geschäft.

Also zwei varianten für wo man "morgen" platzieren kann:

- Die Variante mit "morgen" vor dem **nicht** wäre richtig, wenn Du meinst, dass Du die Blumen nicht morgen kaufst und es betonen willst. Das könnte böse gemeint sein, als ob Du ausdrücken willst, dass Du vorhattest die Blumen morgen zu kaufen, aber jetzt bist Du böse oder sauer und willst es nicht mehr tun. Wobei hier die Betonung in der Aussprache eine Rolle spielt.

Du könntest hier stattdessen auch sagen:

> Ich kaufe dir **keine** Blumen zum Geburtstag.

- Die Variante mit "morgen" nach dem **nicht** wäre korrekt, wenn Du Ausdrücken willst, das Du die Blumen an einem anderen Tag kaufen wirst, z.B. heute statt morgen!

Du könntest hier stattdessen auch sagen:

> Ich kaufe dir Blumen zum Geburtstag.

oder

> Ich möchte/werde dir zum Geburtstag Blumen kaufen.

ohne "im Geschäft", weil dies im Prinzip überflüssig ist (Siehe Kommentar von Christian Geiselmann).